# Repeated measures with adonis in R

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, manova

I have the following experimental design: 9 mice (`mouseID`) were assigned to three different treatments (n=3 per `treatment` level) and we estimated the composition of microbial species in the gut at 5 time points (by 16S sequencing). I would like to know if the community differs between the 3 treatment levels and was thinking of using `adonis` from the R `vegan` package to test for this.

I have a couple of quesitions:

**1. what would be the best matrix for the response variable?** 
The raw matrix of read counts of species (OTUs) per sample? or some measure of beta diversity like Unifrac or bray curtis?

**2. what is the best way of setting the model?**

In looking for answers, I have seen two model formulations online that appear to fit my design:

```
adonis(matrix~treatment + mouseID,data=data,strata=mouseID)
```

and

```
adonis(matrix~treatment,data=data,strata=mouseID)
```

which would be preferable for this design?

thanks for any help!